# How to correctly format a postgres timestamp with timezone date using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm moving from `moment` to `date-fns` and need some advice.

I have a `postgres` timestamp-with-timezone and I'm looking to format it like `MAR 2 AT 1:30 PM`.

Here is my solution using `date-fns`.

```js
import { format, parseISO } from 'date-fns';

const date = parseISO(message.updated_at); // this is from postgres
const md = format(date, 'MMM d').toUpperCase();
const hm = format(date, 'h:m a');
const formattedTimestamep = `${md} AT ${hm}`;
```

Is there a more correct or less verbose way?

Comment: You could do something like the following - `const formatted = format(date, "MMM d @ h:m a").toUpperCase().replace("@", "AT")`, but it's not really "more correct" than what you're already doing.

Comment: date-fns has formatISO9075 now, just use that

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*I got an answer over in the [date-fns github issues](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1652).*</sub>

There's a small useful sentence in [the docs for `format`](https://date-fns.org/v2.10.0/docs/format).

> *The characters wrapped between two single quotes characters (') are escaped.*

This leads to this more succinct version of the code.

```js
const formattedTimeStamp = format(parseISO(message.updated_at), "MMM d 'AT' h:m a").toUpperCase();
```

Comment: date-fns has formatISO9075 now, just use that